# How to add custom property to user control for binding purposes?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, user-controls

I am making a user control named `MusicalNotationBox` to store **only 1** `MusicalNotation` (it's an obligatory for a `MusicalNotationBox` to have a non-null `MusicalNotation` object binded). And I need to bind the `MusicalNotation` property from the xaml (mvvm) to the one in my `MusicalNotationBoxModelView`.

`MusicalNotationBox` is a UserControl which used to visualize a particular `MusicalNotation` in a given collection.

So, I would like to be able to do it this way (with my ModelView as `DataContext`, ofc)

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding ListOfMusicalNotations}>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <c:MusicalNotationBox MusicalNotation={Binding MusicalNotation}/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

(Added ItemsControl tag to clarify the way how `<MusicalNotationBox>`, I think, should used.)

How to achieve this?

---

EXTRA :

**This is my MusicalNotationBox.XAML** (Just in case it's needed)

```
<UserControl x:Class="NumberedMusicalScoresUserControl.MusicalNotationBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NumberedMusicalScoresUserControl.MusicalNotationBoxProperties"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:DotConverter x:Key="DotConverter"/>
    <local:NoteConverter x:Key="NoteConverter"/>
    <local:AccidentalConverter x:Key="AccidentalConverter"/>
    <local:BackgroundConverter x:Key="BackgroundConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="OemPeriod" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="Blank"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D0" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="Rest"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D1" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="N1"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D2" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="N2"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D3" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="N3"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D4" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="N4"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D5" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="N5"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D6" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="N6"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D7" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="N7"/>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="P" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="SHARP"/>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="T" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="FLAT"/>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="OemPlus" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="OCTAVE+"/>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="OemMinus" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="OCTAVE-"/>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="OemPeriod" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="DOT+"/>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="OemComma" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="DOT-"/>
</UserControl.InputBindings>

<Grid x:Name="grid" Margin="10,5,10,5"
      HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Background="{Binding IsSelectedOrFocused, Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}, Mode=OneWay}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
               Text="b"
               Visibility="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Accidental, Converter={StaticResource AccidentalConverter}, ConverterParameter=FL, Mode=OneWay}" 
               FontSize="15" FontFamily="CourierNew" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Path Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Stretch="Fill"
          Visibility="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Accidental, Converter={StaticResource AccidentalConverter}, ConverterParameter=SP, Mode=OneWay}" >
        <Path.Data>
            <LineGeometry StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <LineGeometry.Transform>
                    <RotateTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" Angle="30"/>
                </LineGeometry.Transform>
            </LineGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
               Text="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Note, Converter={StaticResource NoteConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" 
               FontSize="15" FontFamily="CourierNew" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Margin="2.5,0,2.5,0"/>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Octave, Converter={StaticResource DotConverter}, ConverterParameter=TOP, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         Margin="{Binding Margin}" Fill="{Binding Fill}" 
                         Width="{Binding Diameter}" Height="{Binding Diameter}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Octave, Converter={StaticResource DotConverter}, ConverterParameter=BOT, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                         Margin="{Binding Margin}" Fill="{Binding Fill}" 
                         Width="{Binding Diameter}" Height="{Binding Diameter}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Dot, Converter={StaticResource DotConverter}, ConverterParameter=RIGHT, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         Margin="{Binding Margin}" Fill="{Binding Fill}" 
                         Width="{Binding Diameter}" Height="{Binding Diameter}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create any additional properties. Your control is defined by only one viewmodel - just use the DataContextProperty([docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx), [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321899/DataContext-in-WPF)). In your case it is automatically set for each of the items - that's the behaviour of WPF. Just bind to any properties you need inside the usercontrol(its dataContext will be initialized automatically by WPF engine)

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfMusicalNotations}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <c:MusicalNotationBox/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

If you want to learn about adding the properties read [Add dependency property to control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815797/add-dependency-property-to-control).

P.S.: Actually you can define your MusicalNotationBox not as a user control but as a template in [resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742538(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MusicalNotationBox">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
</Resources>
```

and use it like

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsTemplate>
    <StaticResource x:Key="MusicalNotationBox"/>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: P.S: Have you read those resources I have linked to you in your last question? It will give you a lot of insights. And try to read some book or complex tutorial on WPF and MVVM. No one can know everything, i agree. But even if asking questions after questions may solve some current concrete problems, in the end you will left you with a lot of vacancies in knowledge.

Comment: Yes I have. Actually it's kinda nice and if I could do something to add "custom" property to the XAML. I just wanna know if that's possible. I even research further each time I get an answer, and try to innovate in my way. So, no, I'm not a helpvam. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: No one has an insurance against it. It is too tempting. But catastrophic in the end.